# OpenLayers 2 - Capture failure of WFS HttpRequest

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, http

I have a WFS Layer whose HTTP Request might fail from time to time. How do I capture the failure?

```
        var opt =  {
            url: widget.options.wfs.url,
            params: {
                request: "GetFeature",
                service: "wfs",
                version: "1.1.0",
                typeNames: widget.options.wfs.featureType.split(",").map(function(str) { return str.trim(); }),
                srsName: widget.map.getProjection(),
            },
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML({})
        }   

        var wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(opt),
            projection: widget.map.getProjection(),
            styleMap: getStyleMap(),
        });


        widget.map.addLayer(wfsLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wfsLayer.events.register('loadend', null, function(event) {
     if (!event.response.success()) {
         // Do here whatever you want!
});
```

does the trick.